# When i used wicked_pdf gem it is redirecting to a view page instead of download option

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wicked-pdf

I want to implement file export to pdf in rails. but instead of the download option its redirecting to a view page http://localhost:3000/xmls?pdf=xml.pdf&template=xmls_controller%2Findex.html.erb

I have used **render** but an error was throwing that's why i used **redirect_to**

```
Template is missing
Missing template xmls_controller/index.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/god/Documents/xml_parsing/xml_parsing/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-c27b19fae6d4/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.2.1/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.3.4/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv
```

/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3.4/app/views"

This is my View page ***xml_parsing/app/views/xmls/index.html.erb***

```
<h1>Welcome !</h1>
<p><%= @user %></p>

<%# View <%= link_to 'Bookmarks', xml_bookmarks_path %>
<div class="container alert alert-light">
  <%# <% binding.pry %>
  <%= link_to 'Create PDF document', xmls_path(@xml, :format => :pdf) %>
  <%= form_tag(xmls_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline", role: 'search') do %>
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: 'Search', class: 'form-control', id: 'search', autocomplete: :off %>
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class: "btn btn-default", id:"search" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<br><br><br>
  <% @xml.each do |x| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <%= submit_tag 'Bookmark', name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" , id: "bookmark"%><br><br>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><%= x.name %></td>  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Citation:</td>
          <td><%= x.citation %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year:</td>
          <td><%= x.year %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>nominal app:</td>
          <td><%= x.nominal_app %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>nominal res:</td>
          <td><%= x.nominal_res %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>headnote:</td>
          <td><%= x.headnote %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>judgement:</td>
          <td><%= x.judgement %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>case no:</td>
          <td><%= x.case_no %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>justices:</td>
          <td><%= x.justices %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>case number:</td>
          <td><%= x.case_number %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>party details:</td>
          <td><%= x.party_details %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>petitioner advocates:</td>
          <td><%= x.petitioner_advocates %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>respondent advocates:</td>
          <td><%= x.respondent_advocates %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>judgement date:</td>
          <td><%= x.judgement_date %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>judgement object id:</td>
          <td><%= x.judgement_object_id %></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <% end %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('turbolinks:load',function(){
        var xmls = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote: {
            url: '/xmls/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
          }
        });
        $("#search").typeahead(null, {
          source: xmls
        });
      })



      $(function() {
        $("#bookmark").on("click", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_controller_url",
            data: "your_form_data"
            success: function(result) {
              // Append the result to a table or list, $("list").append(result)
            },
          });
        });
      });

    </script>
```

This is my controller

```
  def index
    # binding.pry
    # binding.pry
    @user = current_user.email
    search = params[:term].present?
    @xml = if search
      Xml.search(search)
    else
      Xml.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        redirect_to pdf: "xml.pdf",   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
        template: "xmls_controller/index.html.erb"
      end
    end
  end
```

is there any issue with the rendering or template

Comment: which name of view you're trying to convert into pdf? index?

Comment: that table data

Comment: then you don't have to call redirect. just format.pdf {  render pdf: "report_filename"  }

Comment: when i use render its throwing an error 
Template is missing
Missing template xmls_controller/index.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/god/Documents/xml_parsing/xml_parsing/app/views" * "/home/god/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-c27b19fae6d4/app/views"

Comment: I have attached the full error message. can u please help me to fix this @snake

Comment: The root is "Template is missing Missing template xmls_controller/index.html.erb" It's looking for your template in wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `redirect_to` from the controller in `respond_to` pdf
you should use `render` like in the docs of the wicked pdf gem.

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "file_name"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
end
```

Comment: when i did so it showed an error. thats y i used redirect_to. this is the error
Template is missing
Missing template xmls_controller/index.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :jbuilder]}

Comment: Can you try it with - template: "xmls/index.html.erb" What you are using is xmls_controller/index.html.erb so try to remove controller from this it should route you to the path.